Prove that: $a_b = c_b, b_a = c_a, a_c = b_c ⇔ \frac{s_1}{s_6}+ \frac{s_3}{s_2}+ \frac{s_5}{s_4}=3$.
the problem
Let $M$ be a point inside a triangle $ABC$ and
$A1, B1, C1$ the intersections of lines AM, BM and CM with lines BC, CA and AB, respectively. We denote by $s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5$ and $s_6$ the areas of the triangles $MBA_1,
MCA_1, MCB_1, MAB_1, MAC_1$, respectively $MBC_1$. Let
$a_b = d (A_1, BB_1),
a_c = d (A_1, CC_1), ba = d (B_1, AA_1), b_c = d (B_1, CC_1), c_a = d (C_1, AA_1),
c_b = d (C_1, BB_1)$.
Prove that:
$a_b = c_b, b_a = c_a, a_c = b_c ⇔ \frac{s_1}{s_6}+ \frac{s_3}{s_2}+ \frac{s_5}{s_4}=3$.
my idea
drawing

Ok, so we have to take 2 cases. I was able to do only one of them:
case1: We know that $a_b = c_b, b_a = c_a, a_c = b_c$. We show that $\frac{s1}{s6}+ \frac{s3}{s2}+ \frac{s5}{s4}=3$.
we can write $s1=BM* a_b/2, s6=BM*c_b/2$ and because of the fact that $a_b=c_b$ we arriveto the conclusion that $s1=s6=> \frac{s1}{s6}$
by analogous we get that $\frac{s3}{s2}=1, \frac{s5}{s4}=1$ and by summing them up we get the desired equality.
case 2: We show that $a_b = c_b, b_a = c_a, a_c = b_c$. We know that $\frac{s1}{s6}+ \frac{s3}{s2}+ \frac{s5}{s4}=3$.
I thought of using similarity but I don't know where to begin.
hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Hint: What can we say about $ \frac{s_1} { s_ 6} \times \frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} \times \frac{s_3} {s_ 2} $?

 By Ceva's theorem, $ \frac{s_1} { s_ 6} \times \frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} \times \frac{s_3} {s_ 2} = 1$.

Hence, conclude that $\frac{s_1} { s_ 6} +  \frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} + \frac{s_3} {s_ 2}  = 3$ if and only if $s_1= s_6 , s_5= s_4, s_3=s_2$ if and only if $ a_b = c_b, b_a = c_a, c_b = a_b$.

 By AM-GM,  $ \frac{s_1} { s_ 6} + \frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} +  \frac{s_3} {s_ 2}  \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{ \frac{s_1} { s_ 6} \times \frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} \times \frac{s_3} {s_ 2} } = 3$.


 Since equality holds, this means that $ \frac{s_1} { s_ 6} = \frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} = \frac{s_3} {s_ 2} = 1 $, establishing the first iff.


 Finally, note that $\frac{ s_1}{s_6} = \frac{ a_b}{c_b}$, establishing the second iff.


Heii! you reffer to the fact that $ \frac{s_1} { s_ 6} \times \frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} \times \frac{s_3} {s_ 2} =\frac{a_b}{c_b}* \frac{b_c}{a_c}* \frac{c_a}{b_a} \leq (\frac{s_1} { s_ 6} +\frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} + \frac{s_3} {s_ 2} )^3/27$? If yes I don't know what to do forward

@PamMunozRyan you are close. Can you find the value of $\frac{s_1} { s_ 6} \times \frac{s_5 }{ s_ 4} \times \frac{s_3} {s_ 2}$ to finish your argument?

@DS I tried to find it...it must be 1...but I got stuck

@PamMunozRyan what is $s_1/s_2$?

@DS is it $\frac{a_bMB}{a_cMC}$?

Try expressing it without using $a_b$ and $a_c$.

@DS aaaaa....$\frac{BA_1}{A_1C}$ and then by analogous we get the other fractions and we use the theorem of ceva that says that the product is 1...is it right?

Yes, that's right.

@PamMunozRyan Note that we want $ \frac{ s_1}{s_6}$ (not $\frac{ s_1}{s_2}$). And in particular, (highlight text to review) $\color{white}{ \frac{ s_1}{s_6} = { a_b } { c_b} }$.
